# deploying a React app that uses a Flask backend

Tags: reactjs, flask

I am trying to deploy a `React` app that uses a `flask` backend.
I've never done this, so I would like to clarify some stuff.
Do we first have to deploy the `flask` backend somewhere and make the `React` frontend call that API instead of `localhost`?

If so, do we have to separately deploy the frontend after doing this?

What is the brief flow of this process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this goes towards preferences and common practices, but if it was up to me I would deploy the backend first and make sure the fronted works before I deploy that too. It is not very uncommon to have a separate frontend and backend team, which results in separate deploys, but this is usually coordinated so that you can do simultaneous deploy if there are breaking changes.